# Can I pull up a UIActionSheet with a touchable background?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactionsheet, touch-event

I have a `UIPickerView` on a `UIActionSheet`.  Right now the `UIActionSheet` makes the view behind the `UIActionSheet` not touchable.  Is there a way that I can make it touchable?  Or is that just how a `UIActionSheet` works?

Comment: This is a complete misuse of `UIActionSheet`. It is not designed to have subviews added to it. It is quite possible that some future update of iOS will come with a revamped UI for an action sheet. And when it does, everyone that is doing things like this (adding subviews) are going to have to redo a bunch of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to make the view behind the `UIActionSheet` touchable without dismissing it first.  They're meant to be modal, i.e. require the user's attention before being dismissed.

From [`UIActionSheet` class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (emphasis mine):

> For applications running on iPhone and iPod touch devices, the action sheet typically slides up from the bottom of the window that owns the view. For applications running on iPad devices, the action sheet is typically displayed in a popover that is anchored to the starting view in an appropriate way. **Taps outside of the popover automatically dismiss the action sheet, as do taps within any custom buttons.** You can also dismiss it programmatically.

I suppose a way around this could be that you just create your own view that displays similarly.  For example, create a `UIView` that you can animate the same (slide up) when a button is pressed.  This `UIView` can contain your `UIPickerView` and whatever else you need (probably a cancel button to dismiss it).

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Schweet!  I guess I'll change it over to a UIView.  Thanks rog!